# How to know if a branch is master branch or not?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I have a script which will fetch me all the branch of the repo and it will also do other stuff. I want to know this "Is there any git command which will tell a branch is master or not?"

Comment: `master` is just a convention. You can call the "master" branch whatever you want, for example, in one of my main projects, it's called `v3.0`.

Comment: If you run `git branch`, you will get output telling you what the current branch is.

Comment: @MarounMaroun - "master" is not a notation, it's a convention, and it's the default name for the first branch in a new repository. You can use any name for your "main" branch...

Comment: @Amit that's what I meant to say, you worded it better :) thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can run

```
git remote show origin
```

after you have cloned the repo.

origin is usually the name for the default remote. When you clone a repository, this is automatically set up for you. If you run `git remote show origin`, it will show you the URL for the repo, its HEAD, the branches on the remote, and any local branches tracking those remote branches.

So the branch next to `HEAD branch:` in the output of the command will be your `master` branch.

**Correction:** Note that, this is assuming the git repository has followed convention, by setting HEAD to the master or main branch that is stable for use. Their HEAD may point to any branch of their choice, and in that case your `HEAD branch:` will point to that specific branch.

Comment: It will be the branch that is checked out by default when you clone that repository. That's the *entire* meaning of the `HEAD` ref in a bare remote, nothing more.

Comment: Yes, but will HEAD not point to the main or master branch on most git repositories when we clone them?

Comment: Yes it will, but that is also "by convention", a team is free to change that HEAD ref if they want you to default to a develop branch, as an example.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Thank you for the clarification, I have corrected the answer.

Comment: However, having said that, the question is also open for interpretation because since any team can put a different meaning on both the branch *named* master, as well as which branch they consider the "main" branch, the question is far from clear. Given the normal definition of what the master branch is, your answer is the most reasonable one.

Comment: So: `git remote show origin | awk '/HEAD branch:/ {print $NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

please use following command which will not show only master branch instead it will show all the local and remote branch

```
git branch -avv
```